# Why can't F# infer the type of this statement?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, type-inference

```
/// I can't do this
let max =  float n |> sqrt |> int64 |> Math.BigInt

/// But this is allowed
let max =  Math.BigInt(float n |> sqrt |> int64)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Class constructors cannot be used without arguments.  You can write

```
let max =  float n |> sqrt |> int64 |> (fun x -> Math.BigInt(x))
```

if you like.  (Offhand I don't know the reason for this restriction, though.)

Comment: No, in this context it's a function defined in http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/FSharp.Core/Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.html

Comment: Also can you tell me where to find the square root for a BigInt?

Comment: There is no Sqrt function defined for BigInt in the library.

Comment: @Brian do you know if there will be one?

Comment: No, I don't think one is planned for .Net 4.0's System.Numerics.BigInteger.  You can always author your own.

Answer (score 0):

In my version of F# (1.9.4.19 on Mono), both versions fail with:

> `The member or object constructor
>   'BigInt' takes 0 argument(s) but is
>   here given 1. The required signature
>   is 'Math.BigInt()'.`

I can use

```
let max =  float n |> sqrt |> int64 |> Math.BigInt.of_int64
```

to get a `bigint` or

```
let max =  float n |> sqrt |> int64 |> Math.BigInt.FromInt64
```

to get a `Math.BigInt`.